# Replace the math expression with the calculated result

Tags: notepad++

Example:

- Before : `1+1,1-1,1*2,1/3`
- After :   `2,0,2,0.3`

I have to use notepad ++ because I work with yml file.

I tried using Textfx, but it only pops up a result window

I tried the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/968315/search-and-replace-math-operations-with-the-result-in-notepad?rq=1). But it only calculates multiplication and division and the expression must be in " ".

I need to calculate about 14400 lines like that

Please help me to write a script that resembles the answer [there](https://superuser.com/questions/968315/search-and-replace-math-operations-with-the-result-in-notepad?rq=1) but works with my case

Comment: The answer must be in quotes but your example doesn't include quotes? Your related answer shows what you have to do - not use Notepad++. Use an application that's supposed to do calculations and/or use a programming language and write a script for it.

Comment: Can you help me write a script?

Comment: A script is the same as the answer in:
https://superuser.com/questions/968315/search-and-replace-math-operations-with-the-result-in-notepad?rq=1
But it works with my case
I am very thankful